# How to use the getter method which is stored in mongodb for some other POJO class?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am having one class which is having getter and setter methods i am storing that getter method in mongodb with some other collection. After getting the method name from DB how to access that method. Whether it is possible to do like this or not?

```
public class MappingAlgorithmScoreGenerationRules {

    @Field(value = FieldNames.CATEGORY)
    private String category;

    @Field(value = FieldNames.ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    private MappingScoreGenerationLogic attributeName;

    @Field(value = FieldNames.PRIORITY)
    private Integer priority;

    @Field(value = FieldNames.ATTRIBUTE_SCORE)
    private Integer attributeScore;

    @Field(value = FieldNames.FINAL_THRESHOLD)
    private Integer finalThreshold;

    @Field(value = FieldNames.RESULT_COUNT)
    private Integer resultCount;

    @Field(value = FieldNames.NORMALIZED_VALUE)
    private Integer normalizedValue;

    @Field(value = FieldNames.GETTER_METHOD)
    private String getterMethod;
}
```

This is the class where i am storing the method name.

```
public class MatchEntry {

    private double matchedWeight;

    public double getMatchedWeight() {
        return matchedWeight;
    }

    public void setMatchedWeight(double matchedWeight) {
        this.matchedWeight = matchedWeight;
    }
}
```

getMatchedWeight is the method name i am going to store in the DB MappingAlgorithmScoreGenerationRules.

After getting the method name how to access the method name? 
I want to access like
For example: `MatchEntry.(the value get from db)`

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection API - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

```
Method methodToInvoke
  = MatchEntry.class.getMethod("methodName", methodParams,..);
methodToInvoke.invoke(matchEntryInstance, params,..);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can achieve method access by name using reflection (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).
This is a tutorial you may be able to use to lean more about this language feature: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-java/

In your example, let's say you have loaded an instance of `MappingAlgorithmScoreGenerationRules` from the database, whose `getterMethod` attribute returns "getMatchedWeight".
Let's also assume that you have an instance of `MatchEntry`.

You would then access as follows:

```
MappingAlgorithmScoreGenerationRules rules = ....; //load from DB
MatchEntry entry = ...; //wherever it comes from

String getterMethodName = rules.getGetterMethod();

Method getter = MatchEntry.class.getMethod(getterMethodName);
Object value = getter.invoke(entry);
```

This code snippet omits Exceptions, in particular `NoSuchMethodException` and `InvocationTargetException`.

---

Please note that if you choose this approach, and depending heavily on the rest of your domain model, you will also need to be very careful with assumptions about the return type of the actual value (unless you can somehow guarantee that they are all the same, in which case you could cast the value).

Code that uses reflection is also inherently brittle and prone to failure as soon as you refactor. Imagine you have a populated database with these rules, and during a code review a couple of methods are renamed. Inoccuous change? Or will your entire setup break on the next deploy?

A (type-)safer approach might be to ensure all entries and related objects derive from an interface that standardises the return type on a `getValue(String attributeName)` method, so instead of messing with reflection you might do:

```
MappingAlgorithmScoreGenerationRules rules = ....; //load from DB
MatchEntry entry = ...; //wherever it comes from

String attributeName = rules.getAttribute(); //instead of 'getterMethod'

Object value = entry.getValue(attributeName);
```

where MatchEntry.getValue might be defined as:

```
public Object getValue(String attribute) {
    switch(attribute) {
        case "matchedWeight": return getMatchedWeight();
        default: return null; //or you could throw an exception
    }
}
```

This would easily survive any kind of method name refactoring and reorganisation, but adds the overhead of adding a case to the switch for every new attribute.

This problem could be partially solved with a runtime annotation that essentially binds an attribute name to a getter method, e.g.:

```
public class MatchEntry implements Matchable {

    private double matchedWeight;

    @MyCustomAnnotation("matchedWeight")
    public double getMatchedWeight() {
        return matchedWeight;
    }

    public void setMatchedWeight(double matchedWeight) {
        this.matchedWeight = matchedWeight;
    }
}

public interface Matchable {
    default Object getValue(String attributeName) {
        //read methods annotated with 'MyCustomAnnotation's in current class and call the one with matching value
    }
}
```

Your `getValue(String attributeName)` would be tasked with reading these annotations and dynamically figuring out which getter to call. Still requires the annotation to be added everywhere it's needed, but at least it's with the getter and not hidden in some switch that's potentially duplicated across multiple class definitions.
Instead you just need a single default definition in the parent interface, as hinted above.